# Merge values of a data frame to another data frame by matching value and column name in r

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I have two data frames.

```
    Var1           Freq
1   Cafeteria      1
2   Department 3   16
3   Lobby(TT)      2


   X__1  Department1  Department2  Department3  Cafeteria  Lobby(TT)  Lobby(Music Band)
1  Joe   0            0            0            0          0          0
2  Oliver0            0            0            0          0          0
3  Jack  0            0            0            0          0          0
4  James 0            0            0            0          0          0
```

What I want to do is to take the first row from the second data frame and assign values of the `Freq` of the first data frame to the first row of the second data frame where the column names of the second data frame is same as the first data frame `Var1` value.

Actually I have 4 data frames like the first one each corresponding to the 4 rows of the second data frame. If I can match the first data frame to the first row of the second data frame, I can loop through the same logic for the rest of the rows in the second data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
df2[df1$Var1] <- as.list(df1$Freq)
df2
#    X__1 Department1 Department2 Department3 Cafeteria Lobby(TT) Lobby(Music Band)
#1    Joe           0           0          16         1         2                 0
#2 Oliver           0           0          16         1         2                 0
#3   Jack           0           0          16         1         2                 0
#4  James           0           0          16         1         2                 0
```

---

If we have 4 data.frames like the first one i.e. 'df1' and corresponding datasets like 'df2'.  Assuming that the object names for the set of datasets are 'df1a', 'df1b', 'df1c', 'df1d' and the corresponding sets of other dataset is 'df2a', 'df2b', 'df2c', df2d'

```
Map(function(x, y) {
       y[x[['Var1']] <- as.list(x[['Freq']]
       y}, mget(paste0("df1", letters[1:4])), mget(paste0("df2", letters[1:4])))
```

It would be better to keep objects in a `list` instead of multiple objects in the global environment.

---

Based on the comments, there are 4 datasets similar to the first one i.e. 'df1' and a single data.frame 'df2'.  We need to replace the values in 'df2' based on the matching columns in 'df1' type data.frame so that each row will be filled from each of the values from that datasets.

```
lst <- list(df1a, df1b, df1c, df1d)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df2))) df2[i, lst[[i]]$Var1] <- lst[[i]]$Freq
```

Comment: when I try this without the `Map` function I get this error `Warning: Error in Summary.factor: 'min' not meaningful for factors`

Comment: @simplelenz  Looks like you have `factor` column.  Convert it to `character` and it will work. i.e. `df2[as.character(df1$Var1)] <- as.list(df1$Freq)`

Comment: Thanks. this works and your answer is really good since it is very short. One more thing, what I really want to do is something like this, I take the first row of the `df2` and merge the values of the `df1a` and then take the second row of the `df2` and merge with `df1b`. like wise for the four rows of the `df2` merge values of four `df1` data frames. Any help? I'm trying to figure out using your answer but if you can provide is earlier than me figuring out,  that is great. Thanks again!

Comment: @simplelenz  It is not clear based on your description

Comment: I edited the question now. it is to take the first row of the `df2` and match the `Var1` values of `df1` with the column names of `df2` and replace values of the first row of the `df2` with `Freq` values of `df1`

Comment: I got the answer.  inside a for loop i selected the each row and assigned corresponding values. Can you edit the answer so that I can accept it as the answer?
`for (i in 1:4) {
      df2[i, as.character(df1$Var1)] <- as.list(df1$Freq)

    }`

Comment: @simplelenz  Sorry, I was a bit busy.  I looked at your post, but couldn't find any new example to try

Comment: my df1 changes in each iteration of the for loop. That code is in my real project.

Comment: @simplelenz  I updated the post.  But, I havent tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt=data.frame(Var1=c("Cafeteria","Department3","Lobby_TT"),
              Freq=c(1,16,2))%>%
  mutate(Var1=as.character(Var1))

dt1=data.frame(X__1=c("Joe","Oliver","Jack","James"),
               Department1=c(0,0,0,0),
               Department2=c(0,0,0,0),
               Department3=c(0,0,0,0),
               Cafeteria=c(0,0,0,0),
               'Lobby_TT'=c(0,0,0,0),
               'Lobby_Music'=c(0,0,0,0))%>%
  mutate(X__1=as.character(X__1))


dt1%>%
  tidyr::gather(X__1,-value)%>%
  setNames(c("X__1","Var1","value"))%>%
  left_join(dt,by=c("Var1"))%>%
  tidyr::spread(Var1,Freq)
```

In result:

```
   X__1 value Cafeteria Department1 Department2 Department3 Lobby_Music Lobby_TT
1   Jack     0         1          NA          NA          16          NA        2
2  James     0         1          NA          NA          16          NA        2
3    Joe     0         1          NA          NA          16          NA        2
4 Oliver     0         1          NA          NA          16          NA        2
```

Comment: how to get the result to a data frame variable?